# Search content and creating custom selector filters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want ckack in table if there are row similar (in column "title 1" and "title 3") get this second row ("tr") `background-color: red;`.

[image]

In the this table both rows in column "title 1" and "title 3" have similar content so second row(if it was more of two rows similar all rows except first row get css.) get css `background-color: red;`, How is it by jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vrPNj/1/

And the code:

```
var vals = [];
var tr = $('tr');

tr.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.children(':first').text() + $this.children(':last').text();
    vals.push(val);
});

for(var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++){
    for(var n = 0; n < vals.length; n++){
        if(n !== i){
            if(vals[i] === vals[n]){
                tr.eq(i).addClass('duplicate');
                tr.eq(n).addClass('duplicate');
            }
        }
    }
}

tr.filter('.duplicate:first').removeClass('duplicate');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, this should work:

```
var rows = [];

$('#your_table tr:eq(1) td').each(function() {
  rows.push($(this).text());
});

$('#your_table tr:not(:first)').each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).text() != rows[i]) {
    $('#your_table tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').css('background-color', 'red');

    return false;
  }
});
```

It's far from optimized, though, so I'll leave that to you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the OP was looking for, so I think we were implementing different things completely.